# Algorithm to determine that a 2x2 square contains the numbers 1-4 (no repeats)

Tags: c++, algorithm

What would be an applicable C++ algorithm to determine that a 2x2 square (say, represented by a 1d vector) contains the numbers 1-4?  I can't think of this, although it is quite simple.  I would prefer to not have a giant if statement.

Examples of appropriate squares

```
1 2
3 4

2 3
4 1

1 3
2 4
```

Inappropriate squares:

```
1 1 
2 3

1 2 
3 3

1 2
4 4
```

Comment: "I would prefer to not have a giant if statement." why not? make it work first. you can make it work better/faster later.

Comment: I suppose you are correct.  I may try it with a giant if statement.   So there will be 12 ANDs for each indice ;)

Comment: @LeleDumbo: "Why not"? Because a good solution is actually *less* work than the giant `if` statement.

Comment: that's fine and doesn't have to be found first. making it work first will reveal clues leading to optimizations. at least that's how I learned to optimize my code. if nothing is even working in the first place, what can I optimize?

Comment: When representing the matrix as a vector, are the elements of the array to be stored in row-major or column-major order?

Answer (score 4):

I would probably start with an `unsigned int` set to 0 (e.g., call it `x`). I'd assign one bit in `x` to each possible input number (e.g., 1->bit 0, 2->bit 1, 3->bit 2, 4->bit 3). As I read the numbers, I'd verify that the number was in range, and if it was, set the corresponding bit in `x`.

At the end, if all the numbers are different, I should have 4 bits of `x` set. If any of the numbers was repeated, some of those bits won't be set.

If you prefer, you could use `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>` instead of the bits in a single number. In this case a single number is probably easier though, because you can verify the presence of all four desired bits with a single comparison.

Comment: +1, although for starters it might be easier to understand an array of 4 `bool`

Answer (score 1):

```
bool valid(unsigned[] square) {
    unsigned r = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        r |= 1 << square[i];
    return r == 30;
}
```

Just set the appropriate bits, and check whether all are set at the end.

Though it assumes the numbers are smaller than `sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's represented by a vector and we just want something that works:

```
bool isValidSquare(const std::vector<int>& square) {
    if (square.size() == 4) {
        std::set<int> uniqs(square.begin(), square.end());

        return uniqs.count(1) && uniqs.count(2) && uniqs.count(3) && uniqs.count(4);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a static bitset for corresponding bit 1-4 set, and another one with all bits unset.
2. Traverse through the vector, setting the respective bit in the 2nd set for current vector element.
3. Compare the 1st and 2nd set. If they match, the square is appropriate. Otherwise, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard library for this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input{1,5,2,4};

    sort(std::begin(input), std::end(input));
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
       << std::equal(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::begin({1,2,3,4}));
}
```

Comment: That is ... extreme overkill, and probably not very performant.

Comment: I agree, if performance is a serious issue, but couldn't figure this from OP's question. And probably the killing part is the sorting (O(N log N)), as the std::equal should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your inputs are only 1 to 4 numbers (assumption based on your examples), you can actually xor them and check if the result is 4 :

```
if ((tab[0] ^ tab[1] ^ tab[2] ^ tab[3]) == 4)
    // Matches !
```

I had the feeling this would work, but am too tired to prove it mathematically, but this `python` program will prove this is right :

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
good_results = []
bad_results = []

for i in numbers:
  for j in numbers:
      for k in numbers:
        for l in numbers:
          res = i ^ j ^ k ^ l
          print "%i %i %i %i -> %i" % (i, j, k, l, res)
          if len(set([i, j, k, l])) == 4: # this condition checks if i, j, k and l are different
            good_results.append(res)
          else:
            bad_results.append(res)

print set(good_results) # => set([4])
print set(bad_results)  # => set([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```